# Typescript; getting a value by it's key

Tags: typescript, object

I'm trying to get a value from my object through it's key, e.g.:

```
// File where I store my values

export let mess = {

    rpc: `if (args[1].toLowerCase() === 'true' || args[1].toLowerCase() === 'on') {
        conf_vars.rpc = true;
    } else if (args[1].toLowerCase() === 'false' || args[1].toLowerCase() === 'off') {
        conf_vars.rpc = false;
    }`,

    prefix: `Guild.findOne({
        guildID: message.guild.id
    }, async (err, g) => { 
        if (err) throw err;

        if (!g) await new Guild({
            guildID: message.guild.id,
            prefix: args[2].toLowerCase()
        }).save().then(() => message.channel.send(\`Successfully changed the guild's prefix to \${g.prefix}\`));

        else {
            g.prefix = args[2].toLowerCase();
            await g.save().then(() => message.channel.send(\`Successfully changed the guild's prefix to \${g.prefix}\`));
        }
    })`
}
```

and now I want to get those values through it's key;

```
if (Object.keys(vars).some(v => args[0].toLowerCase() === v.toLowerCase())) {

    let newVar = Object.keys(vars).find(v => args[0].toLowerCase() === v.toLowerCase());

    let confVar = mess[newVar];

    confVar(Server, message, args, (await ConfVars.findOne({ guild: message.guild })));
}
```

But I can't seem to get the logic of it right, I've been stumped on this for about an hour now.

[EDIT]: I have fixed my issue, I used functions instead of strings and `eval()`.
Also, the issue with my `confVar` was that I didn't use `mess[newVar]`, which is now edited.

The new code looks like this:

```
// File where I store the functions (values)

export let mess = {

    rpc: function rpc(Server, message: Message, args: string[], conf_vars) {
        if (args[1].toLowerCase() === 'true' || args[1].toLowerCase() === 'on') {
            conf_vars.rpc = true;
            message.channel.send(`Successfully turned the **rpc** option __on__`);
        } else if (args[1].toLowerCase() === 'false' || args[1].toLowerCase() === 'off') {
            conf_vars.rpc = false;
            message.channel.send(`Successfully turned the **rpc** option __off__`)
        } else {
            message.channel.send(`Please look at the proper usage of the command!`);
        }
    },

    prefix: function prefix(Server, message: Message, args: string[], conf_vars) {
        Server.findOne({
            guildID: message.guild.id
        }, async (err, g) => {
            if (err) throw err;

            if (!g) await new Server({
                guildID: message.guild.id,
                prefix: args[2].toLowerCase()
            }).save().then(() => { message.channel.send(`Successfully changed the guild's prefix to ${g.prefix}`) });

            else {
                g.prefix = args[2].toLowerCase();
                await g.save().then(() => { message.channel.send(`Successfully changed the guild's prefix to ${g.prefix}`) });
            }
        })
    }
}
```

````
// The file where I use them

if (Object.keys(vars).some(v => args[0].toLowerCase() === v.toLowerCase())) {

    let newVar = Object.keys(vars).find(v => args[0].toLowerCase() === v.toLowerCase());

    let confVar = mess[newVar];

    confVar(Server, message, args, (await ConfVars.findOne({ guild: message.guild })));
}```
````

Comment: Please consider editing the code here to make a [mcve] as described in [ask].  Right now it looks like an object with some string properties, and code with undefined variables `vars` and `args`. I'm quite worried that it looks like you're planning to [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!) these strings; unless your question is about how best to evaluate strings as code (and the answer would probably be to discourage such a practice), you should edit the code to be actual code to get a good answer.  Good luck!

Comment: Before I move onto my code, I want to say thank you for replying, I appreciate it.

I've managed to fix my old code and improve it by using functions and doing `mess[newVar]` instead of `Object.values(...)` which was in my earlier stages of the code.

Now it works like a charm. :)

Answer (score 0):

What was wrong with my code, which was a lot from a logical perspective, was the following:

- I tried using `Object.values()` instead of simply doing it the "`obj[key]`" way.
- I wanted to use `eval()` alongside code inside of strings in order to execute the code depending on which argument was provided, which I fixed and improved by simply using functions.
- I was trying to get the value by it's key by using `Object.values()`, which is totally incorrect.

The updated code looks better, more effective and way simpler.